# MV 750i image sensor

Tags: canon

I've just bought a second-hand Canon MV 750i camcorder. Unfortunately, its screen doesn't show what I'm looking at. I understand that the problem is with the image sensor, which I want to try to replace myself. I have a repair manual. I got in touch with Canon, but it doesn't have the part and its support wasn't very helpful. Does anyone know the part number and where I might source it?

Answer (score 1):

If Canon no longer has the part, most likely your best bet will be to find another used MV 750i that you can salvage the part from.  If you have a repair manual, you might checking what the part number it lists is and try searching if any surplus places have the part itself.  Some quick looking on eBay shows what appears (or at least claims) to be a compatible part for $20.